# How do I terminate a process started with _spawnl() in a C/C++ Win32 program?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, posix

In pseudocode...

```
processHandle = _spawnl(_P_NOWAIT, "foo.exe", ...);

/* time passes... */
WossnameKillFunction(processHandle);
```

Comment: Why not utilize the Windows API in your Windows program?  If you'd rather use POSIX, why mention the Windows API?

Comment: Both are possible options. If this can't be done with POSIX I'm open to implementing this with suitable Win32 API calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no terminate counterpart to the VC++ function `_spawnl()`, but it does return a Win32 `HANDLE` that you can use:

```
HANDLE handle = (HANDLE)_spawnl(...);
TerminateProcess(handle, exit_code);
```

Note it only returns a `HANDLE` if you call it with one of the `NOWAIT` args.  If not, it will return the process's exit code.

Of course, it's far better if you can somehow communicate to the process that it should exit gracefully.  `TerminateProcess` will prevent any cleanup code from being called.

(And as a small side note: despite what MSDN says about `spawnl()` being a deprecated POSIX function, it's actually never been in any POSIX standard!  As far as I know it originates from QNX.)

Answer (score 3):

[`_spawnl` returns the `HANDLE` associated with the process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wweek9sc.aspx). Therefore you should be able to terminate the process using the plain [TerminateProcess function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714.aspx).